# Simple cumulative increase in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I have an application that increments a Prometheus counter when it receives a particular HTTP request. The application runs in Kubernetes, has multiple instances and redeploys multiple times a day. Using the query `http_requests_total{method="POST",path="/resource/aaa",statusClass="2XX"}` produces a [graph displaying cumulative request counts per instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeqTn.png) as is expected.

I would like to create a Grafana graph that shows the cumulative frequency of requests received over the last 7 days.

My first thought was use `increase(...[7d])` in order to account for any metrics starting outside of the 7 day window (like in the image shown) and then `sum` those values.

I've come to the realisation that `sum(increase(http_requests_total{method="POST",path="/resource/aaa",statusClass="2XX"}[7d]))` does in fact give the correct answer for **points in time**. However, [resulting graph isn't quite what was asked for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KxyZ.png) because the component `increase(...)` [values increase/decrease along the week.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAbcs.png)

How would I go about creating a graph that shows the cumulative sum of the increase in these metrics over the passed 7 days? For example, given the simplified following data

```
| Day | # Requests |
|-----|------------|
| 1   | 10         |
| 2   | 5          |
| 3   | 15         |
| 4   | 10         |
| 5   | 20         |
| 6   | 5          |
| 7   | 5          |
| 8   | 10         |
```

If I was to view a graph of day 2 to day 8 I would like the graph to render a line as follows,

```
| Day | Cumulative Requests |
|-----|---------------------|
| d0  | 0                   |
| d1  | 5                   |
| d2  | 20                  |
| d3  | 30                  |
| d4  | 50                  |
| d5  | 55                  |
| d6  | 60                  |
| d7  | 70                  |
```

Where d0 represents the initial value in the graph

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? I am attempting to do the same and coming up empty

Comment: I'm afraid we didn't

Comment: Is there still no way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question's idea correctly, I think I managed to create such graph with a query like this

```
sum(max_over_time(counterName{someLabel="desiredlabelValue"}[7d]))
```

A graph produced by it looks like the blue one: [image: Cumulatively processed during the last 7 days]

The reasons why the future part of the graph decreases are both because the future processing hasn't obviously yet happened and because the more-than-7-days-old processing slides out of the moving 7-day inspection window.

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus doesn't provide functionality, which can be used for returning cumulative increase over multiple time series on the selected time range.

If you still need this functionality, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It allows calculating cumulative increase over multiple counters. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns cumulative increase over all the time series with `http_requests_total` name on the selected time range in Grafana:

```
running_sum(sum(increase(http_requests_total)))
```

How does it work?

1. It calculates [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) per each time series with the `http_requests_total` name. Note that the `increase()` in the query above doesn't contain lookbehind window in square brackets. VictoriaMetrics automatically sets the lookbehind window to the `step` value, which is passed by Grafana to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) endpoint. The `step` value is the interval between points on the graph.
2. It sums increases returned at step 1 with the [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function individually per each point on the graph.
3. It calculates cumulative increase over per-`step` increases returned at step 2 with the [running_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function.